# What Scala libraries are necessary at runtime?

Tags: scala

What Scala standard libraries are necessary at runtime?

I'm using Scala to write an AWS Lambda handler. When building the deployment package, all of its dependencies get packaged up, including a number of (some pretty bulky) Scala libraries.

I'm wondering if these packages are actually necessary at runtime, since the jars shouldn't know that they were built using Scala (or [according to this discussion](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8159), maybe they should?)

If they are not necessary, I will exclude them from my deployment package and make it smaller, which is great.

The libraries I'm seeing in my dependency closure are below. Would any runtime issues appear if I don't include them in my lambda jars?

```
scala-actors.jar
scala-continuations-library.jar
scala-continuations-plugin.jar
scala-library.jar
scala-parser-combinators.jar
scala-reflect.jar
scala-swing.jar
scala-xml.jar
scalactic.jar
scalap.jar
```

Comment: For ordinary Scala code, only scala-library.jar is required. You only need the others if you have specific code that specifically uses them.